# Is information hiding and encapsulation independent to one another?

Tags: oop, encapsulation, information-hiding

I understand that information hiding and encapsulation are not necessarily the same thing but by definition they seem very synonymous. This has led me to wonder whether one can be present without the other.

Comment: Actually, the first couple sentences in the wikipedia article about encapsulation as it relates to OOP answers this question perfectly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

In simple way I'll try to explain this things :

> Encapsulation is the concept of grouping of related things into one unit.
>
> Information hiding is the concept of restricting an access to the members that we grouped together in above concept.

So if you see, both concepts are similar. Here we can not say there is the dependancy of these concepts on one another.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. Your information hiding definition depends on encapsulation having taken place and yet you state there is no dependency between the concepts.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: We can either hide data or not. So whatever things we are grouping together, should not always be hide. Hiding is depends only on what type of data we want to restrict user to access.  
So that's why I said there is no dependancy between them.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is the possibility to groups related items. These are both member variables and methods.

While information hiding is the possibility to hide the internal state.

However in practice information hiding is often seen as a part of encapsulation.